# Error: The command "android" failed. while trying to install phonegap for mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova

Hello I'm trying to install Phonegap on my mac to build android apps. I've installed the SDK. I'm having trouble mentioning the correct path.
I get this when I echo $PATH:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

And my bash_profile looks like this:

```
xport PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

The phonegap document says to append

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
 to enable ANT
```

I'm confused. How exactly should my PATH look. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reference to java in your path.

I think you miss the $JAVA_HOME\bin part and also you need to export JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME vars in your profile.

and the doc you read is for windows, not osx. For osX, use colon instead of semi colon to separate folders. and variables are defined with dollars, not percent.

if JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME are defined, just add $JAVA_HOME\bin to your export line in bash.profile.

with ant_home and java_home definition, it should look like that :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
export PATH=$PATH:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools:$ANT_HOME\bin:$JAVA_HOME\bin
```

And maybe you still miss some folders in the path, like npm.

Comment: right. But i don't know how to add that. Could you plz tell how to export it.

Comment: first in a shell window, try to do echo %JAVA_HOME% and echo %ANT_HOME% to check if they are defined

Comment: I edited my answer. One problem you had is the ; instead of : (in window ; is the separator in the path but in osx is :)

Comment: my bad, %JAVA_HOME% is for windows, on OSX it should be $JAVA_HOME, sorry. check my edit.

Comment: hi . My .bash_profile looks like this:                         export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
export PATH=$PATH:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools:$ANT_HOME\bin:$JAVA_HOME\bin. And sudo nano /etc/paths command gives me this: /usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin. I added /usr/local/bin after installing npm. The command still wouldn't run. Any suggestions?